# Recursively copy a list python

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn how to use recursion, and I came across this problem: [recursively copy a list to another in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52298662/recursively-copy-a-list-to-another-in-python)

If I have this code:

```
def string_copy(k):
    if (len(k) == 0):
        return k
return k[0] + string_copy(k[1:])
```

How could I adjust it to where my input parameter could be a list of lists?

Comment: You really should use `copy.deepcopy` and not this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be fine for list of lists too.

```
def string_copy(k):
    if (len(k) == 0):
        return k
    return [k[0]] + string_copy(k[1:])
```